# Using a COUNTIFS() Function in Excel to match strings

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm trying to use a simple `COUNTIFS` function to only count the number of values that are not the same as certain other values. My formula looks like this.

```
COUNTIFS('Pipeline Detail'!$K$5:$K$897,"=90%",'Pipeline Detail'!$B$5:$B$897,"<>POWERPOINT!B16")
```

The result of this formula should be a 0. The "`<>POWERPOINT!B16`" should make sure that nothing is returned. However, every time I run this it gives me a value of 6. This makes it clear that the first condition "`=90%`" is working, but that the second one is not.

I have checked for leading or trailing spaces in all relevant values and there are none. I have also just checked to see if the values were actually equal and they are.

If anyone could help me out with this I would be very appreciative..

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you're comparing against the value contained in a cell, use `&` to concatenate the operator and the cell reference, i.e.

```
"<>"&POWERPOINT!B16
```